# Insecure Transport: Weak SSL Cipher

Tags: php, apache

I have a security issue with my client’s security team with my PHP application "Insecure Transport: Weak SSL Cipher". The problem is with the apache server. And I got the fix solution which says to Disable support for weak ciphers on the server. Weak ciphers are generally defined as:
· Any cipher with key length less than 128 bits
· Export-class cipher suites
· NULL ciphers
· Ciphers that support unauthenticated modes
· Ciphers assessed at s

And This can be done through adding this line in the httpd-ssl config
the line is

```
"SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!NULL:!RC4:!RC2:!DES:!3DES:!SHA:!SHA256:!SHA384:!MD5+HIGH:+MEDIUM".
```

Now when I add this line and I start apache then the apache refuses to start!!

Comment: Can you be more specific about "refuses to start" - do you see an error message, on the screen, or in any of your logs?

Comment: Try `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES` and 
`SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES`

Comment: Or better still `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA` and `SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA`

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you pls tell me what is the right place to write this line??

Comment: There should be some already in the `httpd-ssl.conf` file. Replace them in there

Comment: yes it worked!! thank you so much pls make it as answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry can I ask for your help in one more thing in the same problem pls, I have same issue but for SSL Protocol and when I try to write this line "SSLProtocol ALL –SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1" in the server configuration. Then apache  does the same and does not work.

Comment: I think the `SSLCipherSuite` which has `!SSLv3` Not SSL3 means you are already disallowing SSL3